# Different custom domains for GitHub user page and project page?

Tags: github, dns, hosting

Is it possible to associate more than one custom domain with the same GitHub user account? I would like to use one custom domain for my personal page and another custom domain for a project page.

Specifically, I would like www.deeplearningbook.org to show the GitHub pages for the goodfeli/book project, and www.iangoodfellow.com to show the GitHub pages for the goodfeli/goodfeli.github.io user page. (And if I can be ambitious, I'd like blog.iangoodfellow.com to show the GitHub pages for goodfeli/blog)

I have tried a few different ways to set them up, and everything I have done has ended up with one URL or the other working but not both.

---

My current setup is a huge mess, but since a commenter asked me what my name records currently are:

iangoodfellow.com: I deleted all name records after the last failure. namecheap filled in a default parking page thing. I deleted the custom domain field from the goodfeli/goodfeli.github.io repository on github. Strangely, http://goodfeli.github.io successfully loads but https://goodfeli.github.io redirects to the broken www.iangoodfellow.com parking page. I'm not very happy that github is doing that... I didn't realize that taking down goodfeli.github.io was a possible failure mode here.

deeplearningbook.org: I doubt this is the correct thing to do, but it's the only thing I've been able to get to work so far:
Redirect domain: deeplearningbook.org -> https://www.deeplearningbook.org
A record  @   192.30.252.153
A record  @   192.30.252.154
CNAME Record www goodfeli.github.io.

It's that last CNAME record that I think is the problem. Having the goodfeli.github.io CNAME record for www.deeplearningbook.org prevents me from linking a different domain to the goodfeli.github.io personal page.
I haven't been able to figure out how to link www.deeplearningbook.org specifically to the goodfeli.github.io/dlbook project page though.

Comment: How are you pointing your name records?

Comment: I edited the question to add a complete description of my current, broken, setup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in short, through one sub domain exampleUser.github.io, for example, my page https://shushugah.github.io is my main one, and maps to a custom domain https://shushugah.com while https://shushugah.github.io/23 links to a different github page at https://2Jews3Opinions.com One side effect of this is that https://shushugah.com/23 also redirects to https://2Jews3Opinions.com

I detail this in my blog post https://medium.com/@shushugah/2-customs-domains-for-2-github-pages-a8a9e77d3e57